# Django 1.9 CircularDependencyError

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

what can i do with this error???

```
raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: price_schedule.0001_initial, depot.0001_initial
```

even when i run

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

it shows "No changes detected", even though i deleted all migrations file and folder

if run

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

it not showing all of my app

```
Apply all migrations: authtoken, sessions, contenttypes, admin, auth
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Please show full stack trace. Might be interesting to have the content of price_schedule.0001_initial and depot.0001_initial migration files as well.